# Create SVG Object tag with Cached SVG code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I'm trying to use HTML5 localstorage for SVGs.

My existing code works on manipulation of SVG objects, which has "data" attribute, to point to the SVG file url.

[image]

Now, for HTML5 localstorage, I'm able to cache the file contents of the SVG. But I'm not able to put those contents in object tag.

If I append that cached SVG code to DIV, it looks fine, but my app don't do any manupulation of the content properly.

Is there any way, so that I could create a SVG object without the "data" attribute, and put that cached SVG contents inside that?

Or **any way to build Object tag with Custom SVG data, wihout the URL depedency to it?**

Comment: Could you embed `svg` element into `html` document without `object` element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724762/convert-svg-into-base64/ ?

Comment: Gave you tried using a DataURI?